# How can we solve square root by using eval(expression)

Tags: python, eval

I want to make a gui calculator which takes input as a string through buttons

The buttons their content over to a function where they just concatenate and

I have used `eval()` function for solving the expression I get through `entry.get()`

Can anyone tell how can we solve square root within the expression we get like `=2+346-677*78/6+√567+7`... Something like that ,using `eval()` only or any other editing in the code or expression that will help `eval()` to solve the square root problem also that is taken as input in *√* form through button

Answer (score 0):

you use `math.sqrt()`

```
from math import sqrt
print(eval("2+346-677*78/6+sqrt(567)+7"))
```

output

```
-8422.188238200419
```

or if you want only the number containing `√` you can try the following

```
from math import sqrt
import re
stringEx = "2+346-677*78/6+√567+7"
solved = [sqrt(float(sqrts)) for sqrts in [x.replace('√','') for x in re.split('[+\-]',stringEx) if '√' in x]]
```

output

```
[23.811761799581316]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regex:

```py
import re
import math

def replace(expression):
    # Replace the sqrt symbol with the sqrt funcion from the math module
    return eval(re.sub(r'√(\d+)', r'math.sqrt(\1)', expression))
   
print(replace("√100"))                  # 10.0
print(replace("√25 + √36"))             # 11.0
print(replace("2+346-677*78/6+√567+7")) # -8422.188238200419
```

Note that this will not work for complex expressions:

```
print(replace("√(3**2 + 4**2)")) 
# raises SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```